# Using JSON to get data from a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I've read similar questions here and attempted a few of the solutions with no luck.

I'm trying to use `var jQuery_my_array = <?php echo json_encode($my_array); ?>;` to convert.

I know this returns a valid array called `jQuery_my_array`, but I can't get the array contents properly.

I've also tried

```
var jQuery_my_array = <?php echo json_encode($my_array); ?>;
var jQuery_my_array_parsed = JSON.parse(jQuery_my_array);
alert(jQuery_my_array_parsed[2]);
```

I'd like to just do something like `alert(jQuery_my_array[2][0]);` and get the strings I've stored in the php array.

Possible? I'm not a pro coder btw ;)

Comment: try JSON.parse() to decode and then access the data

Comment: Can you provide an example of the contents of `jQuery_my_array`?

Comment: post what var_dump($my_array); returns

Comment: My code is posted and it shows I've tried JSON.parse, or am I missing something?

Comment: You don't need to JSON.parse data that has been passed through json_encode

Comment: `
    $my_array[] = new imageObject ( // 2
    true, // show
    'images/myimage.jpg', // path
    'my title', // title
    'description- some text here', // description
    'keywords- keyword1 keyword2', // keywords
    'tags- tag1 tag2', // tags
    'my copyright', // copyright
    return_image_details_fun($path), // scantlings function
    false, // a boolean
    'my_album_name' // album
    ); // imageObject closure
`

Thanks Jonathan, hope that helps!

Comment: OK- took out the parse and still can't get text out of the array. Best I get is Object object

Thanks @Jonathan Crowe

Comment: @runninghead that is not an array in php or javascript. I'm not sure what it is. How about this. Run `var_dump($my_array);exit;` in php and put the output of that here

Comment: See what you mean @Jonathan Crowe and Sunil. Sorry to be slow responding- chores over the weekend took over :) Sadly the comment box in Stack Overflow only allows a few lines and the var_dump (even one entry of the array) exceeds the allowed. Also, code indenting and back ticks seem really buggy and hitting return just submits the form, aaaah! Any suggestions?

Comment: array(14) { [0]=> object(imageObject)#1 (10) { ["show"]=> bool(true) ["path"]=> string(60) "images/myAlbum/images/myimage.jpg" ["title"]=> string(12) "My Image Tile" ["description"]=> string(220) "description- This is the item description. This is called, 'My Title', and blah blah blah." ["keywords"]=> string(28) "keywords- illustration, image, frog, green" ["tags"]=> string(23) "tags- kids, art, other" ["copyright"]=> string(46) "relevant copyright line" ["scantlings"]=> array(7) {...[1]=> object(imageObject) #2… 
array dump continues with another 14 or so similar object definitions

Answer (score 0):

No need of `JSON.parse`

Try this

```
<?php
$my_array = array("sone"=>12, "sss"=>45);
?>
<script>

    var jQuery_my_array = <?php echo json_encode($my_array); ?>;
    console.log(jQuery_my_array);

</script>
```

Output of the above will be `Object {sone: 12, sss: 45}`
You can use these as `jQuery_my_array.sone`;

If your php array is like `$my_array = array(12, "sss", 45);`
Then can use json as `console.log(jQuery_my_array[0])`;

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are encountering is due to the fact that you are trying to json_encode an array of objects. In order to do this you will need to transform those objects into an array, which can be done by implementing the `JsonSerializable` interface:

```
class imageObject implements JsonSerializable {

    // your object code


    public function jsonSerialize() {
        // one implementation. You could also only return those values you actually need
        return get_object_vars($this);
    } 

}
```

then in your javascript:

```
var jQuery_my_array = <?php echo json_encode($my_array); ?>;
console.log(jQuery_my_array_parsed);
```

Use console.log, not alert. To view the output of the console.log statement open your [javascript console](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console)

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I've looked in to this now and tried a few other ways to get it working too. Would you know what version of PHP you have to be running to get this to work? Also- the method above seems to rely on me altering the php array to get it in to my Javascript. Don't want to seem ungrateful for the assistance, it's just I'm struggling to find a solution that doesn't generate more problems! :) I'm already using jQuery, does that have a simpler method for this circumstance?

Comment: There is really nothing wrong with your javascript, the issue is with the type of data you are trying to json encode. The solution I posted works with PHP version 5.4 and above

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the help. I'm currently ill but will get back to this asap. Really looking forward to cracking this final puzzle for my modals.